# Is it okay to visually align the elements in a logo?

Tags: logo, alignment, best-practice

Sometimes, some elements in logos look off-centre or misaligned even though we align them in the software (mechanically). Is it accepted practice to shift the mechanically aligned elements, so that they look aligned to the human eye?
 For example, in the below picture, the D looks like it is not aligned with the C.[image]

Comment: *Might* want to fix kerning first. That first T.... the O...

Comment: Looks like it was kerned by MS Word :\

Comment: once you fix the kerning, I'd have a look at not trying to make them fill the same space. Divulging is looking very lonely, catastrophe is crowded in comparison. Maybe try get the centre letters to line up too - L over T should match up for me.

Comment: @Tetsujin Let's try those. I also noticed the kerning later. Btw it's a dummy text I made up to show D and C is not lining up visually. The original text is different  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have find an old visual fact.

If you carefully check high quality fonts, you see the glyphs are aligned for even subjective appearance, not for strict alignment of the midlines or edges. The fine placement can be switched on or off or adjusted in typesetting software such as Indesign. For that reason the line startings can seem at first slightly ragged, but as whole it's more pleasing to read.

BTW. Letter spacing isn't especially good in word catastrophy. That disturbs seeing properly other things. You should move pair AT further from C and closer to the next A. Then you can try to fix the C-D-alignment. Here's one attempt to fix the left end, C has its original place, D, A and T are moved:

[image]

**Not asked:** But the whole text needs to be fixed. Check, if you can drop the justifying and try something like this (unfortunately the font is only Arial):

[image]

Comment: The N... G is still painful, as it the V...U. In  fact much of 'divulging' is a bit of a... catastrophe ;-)

Comment: Ironically, the typeface of "divulging" is called optician sans and was marketed as the only font inspired by the eye-charts historically. https://optician-sans.com/